# Error trying to push a project into Heroku

Tags: heroku, github

Environment: Windows 7
I go to Start | Run and type cmd.

I changed to my directory on my local hard drive and I was able to successfully clone the Github project:

```
git clone git://github.com/heroku/ruby-sample.git
```

I then change to the directory:

```
cd ruby-sample
```

I'm able to run the Heroku create:

```
heroku create
```

I log into Heroku via Firefox and I can see my App directory on Heroku.  So far, so good.  Then I try and push:

```
git push heroku master
```

and every time I get the same error:

ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I've Googgled and looked at a number of similar questions; but unfortunately, I'll be the first to admin that Linux is a very weak area for me.  I haven't found an answer that is specific to this setup on a Windows 7 environment.  I do have the Heroku Toolbelt installed.

Thank you!
V

Answer (score 1):

*(I realized I assumed Rails here and you did not specify that. If you aren't using Rails, ignore the comment about RailsInstaller and RailsBridge.)*

You may need to add your ssh key to your heroku setup with:

```
heroku keys:add
```

If you used RailsInstaller, that should just work. If not, and you don't have an ssh key pair, you'll need to look up how to do that first. You can use PuTTY to do that: http://kb.site5.com/shell-access-ssh/how-to-generate-ssh-keys-and-connect-to-your-account-with-putty/

For a full procedure that will get an app bootstrapped onto Heroku with a Rails app, see: http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/installfest